# is it possible to override ifstream::read, ifstream::open methods without deriving child class from ifstream ?? if possible how?

Tags: c++, std, ifstream, istream

```
std::ifstream in;
in.**open**("file path",std::ifstream::in );
in.**read**((char *)&array[0],size);
```

I want to override the **open & read** so that it won't do any file operation and I can write my own open & read functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override methods without deriving new classes. And you can only override virtual methods. But `std::ifstream::open()` and `std::ifstream::read()` are not virtual.

To do what you want, you need to derive a new class from `std::basic_streambuf` and implement the functionality (or lack of) you want, then give an instance of that clasd to `std::ifstream` (or better, `std::istream` directly) via its `rdbuf()` method.